# Movable and "Zoomable" area without using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, web, graph, user-experience

I am currently developing a web-based application for visualizing data. The app is fed with a `json` file,formatted like this:

```
var theData = {
   "nodes":{
      "IBM":{
         "type":"Institution",
         "properties":{
            "founded_in":"1998",
            "director":"whoever"
         }
      },
      "Joseph":{
         "type":"Employee",
         "properties":{
            "Nationality":"bangladeshi"
         }
      },
      [...]
   },
   "edges":{
      "Joseph-IBM":{
         "labeled":"Works at"
      },
      [...]
   }
}
```

**NOTE**: The `json` is not entirely.

This data is loaded into the application and it will show you:

[image: Screenshot of how the app is currently displaying a dataset that has been loaded]

The nodes are draggables alongside the entire screen and both the lines and the label of the relationships are moved accordingly.

**What would I like to?**

I would like to make the surface in which the graph "lays" movable and zoomable, so the UX can be significantly improved. The way I have seen is

- by using a canvas. The problem **I find**, is that the canvas is the first layer and the elements that are inserted in cannot be neither hovered nor clickable (to add events, for example). I do know that those are not really problems, since there is a graph vis that uses ([canvas](https://anvaka.github.io/graph-drawing-libraries/examples/almende_vis/01.basic/)), but I do not know how to solve it.

I am not asking you to give me the exact code (if you want, it would be much appreciated :)), but to help me in finding something to achieve a movable and zoomable surface!

I hope that everthing is clear & Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I think this is the sort of thing that is built into D3.  [Zoom and pan example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4e3925cdc804db257a86fdef3a032a45),  [basic D3 network graph example](http://bl.ocks.org/jose187/4733747).  And [the full gallery of examples](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery).

Comment: Thank you very much @Amy for your contribution. I will take a look at it and try to ajust it to the current display and code. Do you think it would be possible?

Comment: I can't answer that.  I have no idea what your current code looks like.  But probably not.  D3 is easy to learn, though.

Comment: Thank you Amy, best wishes.